How to interpret k6's test results?
How to interpret k6's test results?
The official documentation does explain a bit on the different types of metrics reported by k6 and how to interpret them.
But having read them both, I still am not able to put two and two together. So let me be very specific, is the following correct?

The http_req_duration metric is the sum of:

http_req_blocked: Time in the DNS lookup, connection, and TLS handshake phases.
http_req_sending: Time to send the request.
http_req_waiting: Time waiting for the server to process the request.
http_req_receiving: Time to receive the response.

For example, if you have:

http_req_blocked: 20ms
http_req_sending: 10ms
http_req_waiting: 250ms
http_req_receiving: 20ms

The total http_req_duration would be 300ms.

If so, why it's not matching my following k6 test result, if not, then what's the correct way to interpret k6's test results, including http_req_blocked, http_req_connecting, http_req_duration, http_req_waiting and http_req_waiting?




Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.

The docs on built-in metrics are quite clear what value the http_req_duration Trend metric tracks:

Total time for the request. It’s equal to http_req_sending + http_req_waiting + http_req_receiving (i.e. how long did the remote server take to process the request and respond, without the initial DNS lookup/connection times).

It does not include the timings from http_req_blocked.
